# How to draw data correctly using ReactJS and useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, postgresql, express

I ran into a problem, I can't solve it in any way.

I have a table of orders in my database:
[Table in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBS8f.png)

1. **id** - Order number
2. **items** - Objects in an array with products
3. **transaction_date** - Transaction date

In the console I get an array of objects
[Code and console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uadrz.png)

But I do not know how to write useState to the hook correctly, so that I can then draw the information as in the example in the screenshot
[Screenshot of data rendering on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8Z7h.png)

I will be very grateful for a hint

**Code:**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

import {Card} from "../components/Card";

export const Orders = () => {
  const [orders, setOrders] = React.useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/orders');
        console.log(data);
        //setOrders(data.reduce((prev, obj) => [...prev, obj.items]));
        // setOrders(data.reduce((prev, obj) => [...prev, ...obj.items], [])); // old on mock api
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <div className="content-header">
        <h1>My orders</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="sneakers">
        {(isLoading ? [...orders] : orders).map(item => (
          <Card
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            price={item.price}
            image={item.image}
            loading={isLoading}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Response from the server:**

```
[
    {
        "id": 19,
        "items": "[{\"id\":3,\"title\":\"Men's Nike Blazer Mid Suede Sneakers\",\"image\":\"/img/sneakers/3.jpg\",\"price\":6},{\"id\":2,\"title\":\"Men's Nike Air Max 270 Sneakers\",\"image\":\"/img/sneakers/2.jpg\",\"price\":80}]",
        "transaction_date": "26.06.2022"
    },
    {
        "id": 21,
        "items": "[{\"id\":5,\"title\":\"Men's Sneakers Under Armour Curry 8\",\"image\":\"/img/sneakers/5.jpg\",\"price\":50}]",
        "transaction_date": "26.06.2022"
    },
    {
        "id": 22,
        "items": "[{\"id\":3,\"title\":\"Men's Nike Blazer Mid Suede Sneakers\",\"image\":\"/img/sneakers/3.jpg\",\"price\":6},{\"id\":7,\"title\":\"Мужские Кроссовки Jordan Air Jordan 11\",\"image\":\"/img/sneakers/7.jpg\",\"price\":70}]",
        "transaction_date": "07.07.2022"
    },
    {
        "id": 23,
        "items": "[{\"id\":12,\"title\":\"Men's Nike Kyrie Flytrap IV Sneakers\",\"image\":\"/img/sneakers/12.jpg\",\"price\":100},{\"id\":9,\"title\":\"Men's Nike Lebron XVIII Low Sneakers\",\"image\":\"/img/sneakers/9.jpg\",\"price\":90}]",
        "transaction_date": "07.07.2022"
    }
]
```

Comment: whats the issue youre facing ?

Comment: have you just tried `setOrders(data)` this will give your data under `orders`

Comment: I don't quite understand how to correctly render the data received from the server using useState

Comment: const [orders, setOrders] = React.useState([]);
the orders is tha variable , and setOrder is used to assign the value into the variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and tell me if it works, i always do this to save data in state

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

import {Card} from "../components/Card";

export const Orders = () => {
  const [orders, setOrders] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const {data} = await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/api/orders');
        setOrders(data)
        setIsLoading(false);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }

    fetchData();
  }, []);
  
 if(isLoading) return <h1>...loading</h1>

  return (
    <div className="content">
      <div className="content-header">
        <h1>My orders</h1>
      </div>
      <div className="sneakers">
        {orders && orders.map(item => (
          <Card
            key={item.id}
            id={item.id}
            title={item.title}
            price={item.price}
            image={item.image}
            loading={isLoading}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: It almost worked! And how do I display all the products that are in **items**? Do I need to iterate through the **items** array again? Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/0ygYMTv.png Code: https://i.imgur.com/491MoLl.png

Comment: @markelov yes, you need to iterate through the items array in Card component

Comment: yes, u need to iterate again, u can create in the card component that iteration,you pass the array for the card component  and inside u interate the data, try it and tell me if works

Comment: Unfortunately, I couldn't get to **items**. Code: https://i.imgur.com/C9hX7UB.png

Comment: you need to now pass the data for the Card component, u need to create a propriety called items in Card and pass the items for the component, then u need to iterate the items inside the components.

Comment: can you show what you have in the Card component?

Comment: i create an exemple for u, see this and tell me if u undersand, https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-volhard-w53y43?file=/src/components/Card.tsx

Comment: you need to pass item.items to the Card component like <Card
            items={item.items} .../>

Comment: I can't change the Card component. Since I have product cards displayed on several pages and everything is fine there, the problem is only on the orders page.

We need to sort out the current item.items somehow and draw the already existing component. Code: https://i.imgur.com/UbsLD3o.png

Comment: you have items as props in your Card component but you are not sending any item i didnt mean to change the Card component

Comment: i see, everything you need is interate inside the component, basically u need to do two iterations, see in the link https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-volhard-w53y43?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Okay, it doesn't work for me) Anyway, thank you very much for your help, I am very grateful to you) I will probably need to change the functionality of the orders

Comment: i love helping people,i think you can create a new component and try what i said above, good look with your project.